Should "in spirit and truth" be understood as a hendiadys?
The phrase ἓν διὰ δυοῖν one for two describes two things which become one. When combining both spirit and truth, there are three ways to describe the two.

Use the article with each: τῷ πνεύματι καὶ τῇ ἀληθείᾳ - the spirit and the truth
Begin with the article: τῷ πνεύματι καὶ ἀληθείᾳ - the spirit and truth
Do not use an article: πνεύματι καὶ ἀληθείᾳ - spirit and truth

With respect to worship the difference between these can be illustrated by the Temple, the Holy Place and the Holy of Holies.

A Levite who sang outside - [the Holy Place] and [the Holy of Holies]
A Levite who offers incense inside with a curtain - [the Holy Place and Holy of Holies]
A Levite who offers incense inside with no curtain - [Holy Place-Holy of Holies]

The Levite knows of the presence of both inner rooms. When they remain outside singing, those two are separate and distinct. The Levite who enters to offer incense is in the Holy Place separated from the Holy of Holies by a curtain. When the curtain is removed the Levite who enters is in one room, made up from what had been called Holy Place, Holy of Holies.
John 4:23 (RGT)

“But the hour comes, and now is, when the true worshipers shall worship the Father in Spirit and Truth. For the Father requires even such to worship Him.

The Revised Geneva Translation capitalizes both Spirit and Truth. This makes sense to me since it is the Father's action, which makes πνεύματι Spirit and ἀληθείᾳ Truth. Put differently, if ὁ πατὴρ should be translated as Father, His action, seeking true worshippers prevents understanding πνεύματι καὶ ἀληθείᾳ as merely "spirit and truth."
1 Peter 2:9 (ESV)

But you are a chosen race, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, a people for his own possession, that you may proclaim the excellencies of him who called you out of darkness into his marvelous light.

Revelation 1:6

and made us a kingdom, priests to his God and Father, to him be glory and dominion forever and ever. Amen.

Since believers are priests we are like the Levite who enters the inner place without a curtain.
Should ἐν πνεύματι καὶ ἀληθείᾳ in John 4:23 be understood as a hendiadys, Spirit-Truth?

Definition of "hendiadys" from Oxford Dictionaries:

"the expression of a single idea by two words connected with 'and'."

Both O.D. and wiktionary give "nice and warm", two mutually agreeing words, as examples of hendiadys.
John 4:20-24 is a part of a conversation which has in v24:

"God is spirit, and those that who worship him must worship him in spirit and truth." [spirit and truth as in v23]. My emphasis.

The single idea: worship.
In v20 the woman mentions a place ["this mountain"] and in his reply [v24] Jesus says "God is spirit" and the inference is that the state of a spirit is  not tied to a place. The possibility of his spirit meeting with our spirit is expressed in  Romans 8:16:

"The Spirit himself bears witness with our spirit that we are the children of God."

One who is born again, a child of God, can call God "Father".
Worship here involves two ingredients: 1. The meeting of spirits; ours with His. 2. Truth.
Truth, perhaps at no more than a mustard seed in quantity, is necessary as there could be no other point of contact of God's Spirit with man's than a contact based on truth. John 14:6:

"Jesus said to him, I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father but by me."

Truth however small in quantity would always be big in quality.
In John 4:23 worship is inextricably tied to "spirit and truth". And "spirit and truth" have no partition between them. ["a single container with no partition between them"].
For these reasons I think "spirit and truth" to be a hendiadys of "worship", and "worship" here is by true worshipers because they are "born again."

To keep it simple, worshiping the Father in spirit and in truth is a way of worship.
A similar phrasing is used in Joshua 24:14:

KJV Now therefore fear the LORD, and serve him in sincerity and in truth:

Throughout the bible, spirit is synonymous with the heart, which represents the totality of one's inner self (thoughts, passions, decisions).
According to John 17:17 and Psalm 119:160, the word of God is truth. So worship God according to His word.
So, God must be worshiped in spirit (wholeheartedly, sincerity) and in truth (by His Word).

Normally, a hendiadys is constructed of opposite extremes, for example:

turn not to the right nor left (ie, do not turn in any direction)
heaven and earth = the whole world
in black and white = the whole page/message in black type on a white page
Day and night = continually, all the time
Searched high and low = searched everywhere
Time and again = repeatedly
Neither one nor the other = nothing

Thus, "spirit and truth" would not normally constitute a hendiadys because these are not opposite ends/extremes on some spectrum.
Further, "in spirit and truth" in John 4;23 is not describing a person/Christian but a worship mode; that is, Jesus is saying that all true believers must worship the Father in spirit and truth.  If anything, this "spirit and truth" are two titles of the Holy Spirit (see appendix below), but I would not press this too far.
In English, it is also possible to construct a hendiadys by two nouns where one could have modified another such as the famous Shakespear quote from Macbeth, "full of sound and fury" instead of "furious sound".  In this case, if "spirit and truth" were to be a hendiadys, then an alternate might be "spiritual truth" which makes no sense.
CONCLUSION
"worship in spirit and truth" is simply designating a worship mode from all "true" believers (John 4:23).  This possibly alludes to Rom 8:9 where all must have the Spirit of Christ and truly worship God alone.
APPENDIX - Titles of the Holy Spirit

“the Spirit of God”, 1 Cor 12:3, Matt 3:16, 12:28, Rom 8:9, 14, 15:19, 1 Cor 2:11, 14, 3:16, 6:11, 7:40, 2 Cor 3:3, Eph 4:30, Phil 3:3, 1 Peter 4:14, 1 John 4:2, Rev 3:1, 4:5, 5:6
“the Spirit of the living God”, 2 Cor 3:3
“the Spirit of Christ”, Rom 8:9, Phil 1:19, 1 Peter 1:11
“the Spirit of the Lord”, Luke 4:18, Acts 5:9, 8:39, 2 Cor 3:17, 18, Judges 3:10, 11:29, 14:19, 15:14, Isa 11:2, 59:19, 61:1, 63:14, Eze 11:5, 37:1; 1 Sam 16:13, 14, 1 Kings 18:12, 2 Chron 18:23, 20:14, Mic 2:7, 3:8, etc.
“the Spirit of holiness”, Rom 1:4
“the Spirit of glory”, 1 Peter 4:14,
“the Spirit of grace”, Heb 10:29, Zech 12:10
“the Spirit of truth”, John 14:17, 15:26, 16:13, 1 John 4:6
“The Spirit of wisdom”, Eph 1:17, Ex 28:3, Deut 34:9, Isa 11:2


Can you provide some support for your definition of hendiadys?

@RevelationLad - My answer updated.

Here is a link which begins with discussing the meaning of hendiadys. https://brooklynworks.brooklaw.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2252&context=faculty

It is easy to assume that the word "spirit" always has a supernatural meaning when it appears in scripture.
But "sometimes a cigar is just a cigar".
The word "spirit" can have a more mundane meaning, as in:
Galatians 6:1:


(KJV) … restore such an one in the spirit of meekness …
(NKJV) … restore such a one in a spirit of gentleness …
(ESV) … restore him in a spirit of gentleness …
(BBE) … put such a one right in a spirit of love …
(AMP) … restore such a person in a spirit of gentleness [not with a sense of superiority or self-righteousness] …


Here the word "spirit" refers to one's personal attitude, nothing supernatural.
Scripture often combines "truth" along with an attitude:

1 Samuel 12:24, "… serve him in truth with all your heart …".
1 Kings 2:4, "… walk before me in truth with all their heart and with all their soul …".
1 Kings 3:6, "… he walked before thee in truth, and in righteousness, and in uprightness of heart with thee …".
2 Kings 20:3, "… walked before thee in truth and with a perfect heart …".
Psalms 111:8, "… done in truth and uprightness …".
Isaiah 48:1, "… which swear by the name of the LORD, and make mention of the God of Israel, but not in truth, nor in righteousness.".
1 Corinthians 5:8, "… with the unleavened bread of sincerity and truth …".
Philippians 1:18, "… whether in pretence, or in truth …".

If we consider John 4:23's use of "spirit" as nothing more than attitude, then the expression "in spirit and truth" fits the OP's description: "a single container with no partition. The two come together as one with their own appearance.".
The OP's idea, someone "who worships Him with "the" spirit, someone who has been born again, not someone with "a" spirit", doesn't apply here.
These worshippers will not only believe God's truth, they will enjoy it.
Hebrews 8:10's, "I will put my laws into their mind, and write them in their hearts", is the same message: their minds have the correct facts and their hearts have the correct attitude ("The two come together as one with their own appearance.").
If we read the text in terms of what it actually says, without expecting it to say more, it makes sense.

I say "a" spirit as an example of what must be excluded. Since the Father is seeking something, the Father's action makes definite the something He is seeking. So it cannot mean one's personal attitude because one's personal attitude can be anything including something hostile to God. I agree with your conclusion,. but the example is completely wrong since spirit cannot be "nothing more than attitude" because the Father is not seeking such as those.

The Greek «ἐν πνεύματι καὶ ἀληθείᾳ» could mean, rather than “in spirit and in truth,”1 “in the Spirit, even in the Truth.” («ἐν πνεύματι» need not have the definite article to be translated as “in the Spirit.”2)
The copula καὶ may be epexegetical, further identifying πνεύματι—“Spirit,” i.e., the Holy Spirit, as “the Truth.” In his epistles, the author later wrote, «τὸ πνεῦμά ἐστιν ἡ ἀλήθεια», “the Spirit is the truth.”3
John Paul Heil wrote,4

To worship “in Spirit and truth” is to worship “in the Spirit of truth” that Jesus promised to send his disciples after his death and resurrection (14:17; 15:26; 16:13) as the advocate, the holy Spirit (14;16, 26; 15:26; 16:7), who will represent him and guide them in matters regarding the truth. Since there is a sense in which Jesus himself personifies the truth (14:6), to worship in Spirit and truth or in the Spirit of truth is ultimately to worship in very close union with Jesus.

To be “in the Spirit” means to have the Holy Spirit.5 The Holy Spirit dwells in the Christian, the Christian dwells in the Holy Spirit (hence, “in the Spirit”), and in doing so, the Father and the Son also dwell in the Christian. Indeed, the Father and Son make theirselves a home with the believer.6 Luther on John 14:23: „und wir wollen täglich seine Gäste, ja, Haus- und Tischgenossen sein,“—“and We7 want to daily be his company, yes, house- and table-companions.”8
True worship is in the Holy Spirit (“the Truth”), where the communion9—that is, the participating in and sharing of—the Holy Spirit exists between, not only the Father and the Son, but the entire Church, which is Christ’s own body, for “he who is joined to the Lord is one spirit.”10 Only in the Holy Spirit can Christians worship God how He desires to be worshipped, for “no one knows the things of God except the Spirit of God. Now we have received...the Spirit which is of God.”11




Footnotes




1 as though it were referring to the human spirit2 cf. Rom. 8:9; Eph. 2:22, 6:183 1 John 5:64 Heil, p. 285 cf. Rom. 8:9: But you are...in the Spirit, if indeed the Spirit of God dwell in you.6 John 14:23: «μονὴν παρ᾽ αὐτῷ ποιησόμεθα».7 the Father and the Son8 Luther, § 408, p. 4449 2 Cor. 13:14; Phil. 2:110 1 Cor. 6:1711 1 Cor. 2:11–12






References




Heil, John Paul. 1–3 John: Worship by Loving God and One Another to Live Eternally. Eugene: Cascade Books, 2015.Luther, Martin. Dr. Martin Luthers Sämmtliche Schriften. Book 8. Ed. Walch, Johann Georg. St. Louis: Concordia, 1892.




I think this correctly captures the meaning of "spirit" as used here. I question if treating καὶ as epexegetical is the best approach. The Spirit is called the Spirit of Truth (actually the Spirit of the Truth), yet Jesus is called the Truth. The picture of Father and Son dwelling in the Christian is correct, but here the Son says the Father is seeking Spirit and Truth in true worshippers. I used the Temple to provide a Biblical example of the significance of the different ways the article can be used.
